# Text of a label can't be set from other view controller or it can't set it equal to any string that is being passed by other view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

I have a label named "lblRepeat" in a view controller named "ScheduleEditVC".
And I am setting the text of this label from another view controller named "RepeatVC" using both the parent child relationship and by normal object creation. But the value can't be set. Then I tried to create a label in "ScheduleEditVC" and set it's value in the "RepeatVC" and then made this label equal to "lblRepeat" in the "ScheduleEditVC". But it still doesn't work.
Below is my code

1st way:

```
// directly setting the value using string.
//week is a string
scheduleView.lblRepeat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",week];
```

2nd way

```
//using the parent child relationship
//in the ScheduleEditVC

- (IBAction)btnRepeat:(id)sender 
{
RepeatVC *repeatView1 = [[RepeatVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"RepeatVC" bundle:nil];
repeatView1.scheduleView = self;
[self.view addSubview:repeatView.view];
}
//in the RepeatVC
scheduleView.lblRepeat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",week];
```

3rd Way:

```
//By creating a label
//in the header of ScheduleEditVC
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *txtMyRepeat;
// in RepeatVC
scheduleView.txtMyRepeat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",week];
//in the viewDidLoad of ScheduleEditVC.m
lblRepeat = txtMyRepeat;
```

All ways should work perfectly but they ain't in this case.

Comment: Is the label created at this time? Isn't it nil?

Comment: When is it alloc/init? You may want to have a `NSString` property and set your week to it, and when you load the VC, set it to your label.

Comment: BTW it is a NSString property.

Comment: I mean i have been trying that too.

Comment: Well, anyway, since `week` is a `NSString`, I don't get why you use `stringWithFormat:`. Then, I'd go, as I said, with (in the way of you 3rd way, keeping the order, but changing the lines) `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *txtMyRepeat;` `schedulView.txtMyRepeat` = week;` `lblRepeat setText:week;`. How is declared `lblRepeat`? An `IBOutlet`?

Comment: First I was directly assigning week to the label.text but I just tried  `stringWithFormat` to give it a go too. And that doesn't help too, see `[scheduleView.lblRepeat setText:week];`

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblRepeat;`